# Differences in regex syntax in Python and Java

Tags: java, python, regex

I have a following working regex in Python and I am trying to convert it to Java, I thought that regex works the same in both languages, but obviously it doesn't.

Python regex: `^\d+;\d+-\d+`

My Java attempt: `^\\d+;\\d+-\\d+`

**Example strings that should be matched:**

```
3;1-2,2-3
68;12-15,1-16,66-1,1-2
```

What is the right solution in Java?

Thank you, Tomas

Comment: There are quite a few significant differences between Python and Java, but your regex doesn't manage to stumble on any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is faulty for the input, don't know what you were doing in Python, but this isn't matching the whole strings in any regex I know.

This should do the trick (escaping characters are omitted):

```
^\d+;(\d+-\d+,?)+
```

I.e. you need to continue matching the number pairs separated by commas.

Comment: Thank you, I don't need to match the whole string, I just test if the pattern is in the string, so I test only for the first pair separated by a comma and that is sufficient for me.